# Custom Tab Adapter not showing anything

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following PagerAdapter to display tabs in my Android Fragment:

```
class CustomTabPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = AchievOngoingFragment()
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = AchievDoneFragment()
        }
        return fragment
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = 2

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        var title: String? = null
        if (position == 0) {
            title = "Ongoing"
        } else if (position == 1) {
            title = "Done"
        }
        return title
    }
}
```

Which is set up in my `ProfileFragment` like so:

```
internal lateinit var viewpageradapter:CustomTabPagerAdapter //Declare PagerAdapter

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewpageradapter = CustomTabPagerAdapter(activity.supportFragmentManager)

    viewPager.adapter = viewpageradapter  //Binding PagerAdapter with ViewPager
    tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(this.viewPager)
}
```

With the following layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

The tabs are displayed perfectly fine, but the contents of the ViewPager is empty when it should be the contents of the layout of the Fragments associated with each tab (namely `AchievOngoingFragment` and `AchievDoneFragment`)

Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ChildFragmentManager` here:

```
CustomTabPagerAdapter(activity.childFragmentManager)
```

Comment: Changing it to `CustomTabPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)` doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: @Christopher where you bind your view pager?

Comment: Isn't that done here: `viewPager.adapter = viewpageradapter` ?

Comment: @Christopher you setting adapter here. But where do you initialise ViewPager object?

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter code looks fine, I'd guess that the problem is with your fragments.

Check this [repo](http://%20https://github.com/weibeld/AndroidTabsExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/weibeld/example/tabs/MainActivity.java), it has a working example.

I would recommend you to start with copying [Fragment1](https://github.com/weibeld/AndroidTabsExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/weibeld/example/tabs/Page1Fragment.java) and [Fragment2](https://github.com/weibeld/AndroidTabsExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/weibeld/example/tabs/Page2Fragment.java) from there and using them in your adapter to locate the problem.

Comment: The problem persists, even when copying both the adapter and the fragments ! The viewpager zone is blank. Could that be linked to the fact that my viewpager is in a fragment?

Comment: try having android:layout_height="match_parent" in your viewpager. If that won't help I think it'll require more code from your project to figure out the problem.